# iPhone SDK: Redirecting stderr/stdout to XCode console

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I have a C library that I'm planning to use in an iPhone application. It writes a lot of its debug information to stderr. Is there an easy way to redirect stderr/stdout to my XCode console?

Will I have to write wrappers that call NSLog? If so, what would be the best way of doing so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know that stdout at least already goes to the console.  I am not 100% sure about stderr.

You can simply do a `print`, and it will end up in XCode's console.

Edit: Found some references confirming stderr as well.

Comment: Mmmmm, I'm sure that's what it's supposed to do, but simple statements like fprintf(stdout, "test"); are not visible to me in my console (Run -> Console) when succesfully running the application through Build & Run. Maybe I'm missing something?

Comment: Do your lines end with "\n"?  If not, the buffer may not be written out immediately.  There is a long discussion/argument about this here: http://forums.macrumors.com/archive/index.php/t-147797.html%3C/t-511473.html

Comment: Jeff B: Heh, forgot to flush. Thanks for that, all working! :)

Answer (score 3):

There’s no need to redirect anything, all the output goes to the console already. Try that:

```
fprintf(stdout, "Standard output.\n");
fprintf(stderr, "Standard error output.\n");
```